# Why is long 2500000000 overflowing?

Tags: java, long-integer, integer-overflow

My understanding is that a long in java has a max value of 2^63-1. Any ideas why when storing 50000^2=2500000000 in a long I get -1794967296 considering 2500000000 is less than 2^63-1? Thanks

```
    long l = 50000 * 50000;
    System.out.println(l);
```

I expect the output to be 2500000000, but the actual output is -1794967296.

Comment: that's not long overflow, it's int overflow as you're doing int multiplication. You're using int literals, not long literals.

Comment: `50000 * 50000` != `50000L * 50000L`

Comment: Where is int addition happening?

Comment: `50000` is `int` literal not `long` so you are doing `int` * `int` which is also `int` (regardless of values used and received, that is why overflow happens). Try with `50000L*50000L`.

Comment: ok. that worked. How do I do that for variables? eg: long l = 50000; long n = l * l;

Comment: @Yoni, that example works as expected, `long n = l * l;` produces `2500000000`, demo https://repl.it/@downshift/HumiliatingAltruisticAggregator

Comment: ok I used Long.valueOf(n) in the end. Thanks fr all the help. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1):

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. As a result, if overflow occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the same as the sign of the mathematical product of the two operand values.

You are multiplying two integers that overflow, then store the result in a long, which won't help.

You either have to explicitly use long literals:

```
 long l = 50000L * 50000L;
 long l = 50000L * 50000; // this also works
```

or cast to long before multiplying:

```
 long l = ((long) 50000) * ((long)50000);
 long l = ((long) 50000) * 50000; // this also works
```

See the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) to see why it is enough to only explicitly use one long literal or one casting to long.